# Adding rows of matrix meaning

Tags: matrices

English is not my mother tongue and I'm studying Algebra using a book in english. This sentence came up to me in an exercise 
"every row of matrix A adds to zero".

What does that mean, in concrete?

EDIT:

Full exercise:

If every row of A adds to zero, prove that detA = 0. If every row adds to 1, prove
that det(A¡I) = 0. Show by example that this does not imply detA = 1.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more context. Could you give us the whole exercise?

Comment: it sounds to me that the restriction on the elements of $A$ is that the sum of the elements of an arbitrary row equal 0, so $a_{i,1}+...+a_{i,k}=0$, for a matrix with $k$ columns ..but, I could be wrong, more context would be more helpful.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I read this as follows. Let $A$ have entries $a_{i}^j$, where $i$ is a row index and $j$ is a column index. Suppose there are $N$ columns. Let us consider a fixed row index $i$. Then I sum the elements of that row as follows and I get zero:

$$
s_i = \sum_{j=1}^N a_i^j = 0
$$

I interpret your statement as $s_i=0$ for all $i$, i.e., the sum of each row is zero.